# Configure retry policy pattern

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Is it possible to configure a retry policy of the RetryConfiguration.

I would like to retry the calls of my service with a quadratic pattern.
Like waiting 0.5s, then 1s, then 2s, then 3s...ect, between each calls.

If it is not possible with a Retry pattern, what can I do?

Thanks.

According to the java documentation, I think it's not possible.
But I prefer to ask directly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no convenience API to achieve this.

But you could still do this by following these steps:

1. Implement your own `RetryProvider` say `QuadraticRetryProvider` which implements the interfaces `RetryProvider` and `GenericDecorator`.The most important point is that you should override the `getRetry` method where you add an `intervalFunction`. Refer to the public `DefaultRetryProvider` class for more details.

```java
@Override
    public Retry getRetry( @Nonnull final ResilienceConfiguration configuration )
    {
        ...

        final RetryConfig customRetryConfig =
            RetryConfig
                .custom()
                    .intervalFunction(IntervalFunction.ofExponentialBackoff(your-interval, your-multiplier))
                ...
                .build();

    }
```

2. Create a new resilience decoration strategy that uses the `QuadraticRetryProvider`.

```java
final Resilience4jDecorationStrategy newStrategy = Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.builder().decorators(Arrays.asList(new DefaultBulkheadProvider(),
new DefaultTimeLimiterProvider(),
new DefaultRateLimiterProvider(),
new DefaultCircuitBreakerProvider(),
new DefaultCachingDecorator(),
new QuadraticRetryProvider())).build();
```

3. Use the strategy to decorate and execute your operation

```java
ResilienceDecorator.setDecorationStrategy(newStrategy);
final RetryConfiguration retryConfiguration = RetryConfiguration.of(attempts, waitDuration);
final ResilienceConfiguration configuration =
            ResilienceConfiguration.of("quadratic-retry-config").retryConfiguration(retryConfiguration);
final Callable<?> wrappedCallable = ResilienceDecorator.decorateCallable(()-> your-operation(), configuration);
```